# Redefine the style of acronyms (glossaries)

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

In a paper I'm writing I would like to enter a list of acronyms used, and I'm trying to do with the use of `glossaries` package. The problem is the style in which they appear acronyms. A compilable code is this:

```
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes}
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\acronimo}[1]{%
  \mbox{\sffamily\scshape\MakeLowercase{#1}}}

\makeglossaries
\newacronym{AAA}{AAA}{Abcde Abcde Abcde}

\begin{document}

\gls{AAA}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

I would like to get all the acronyms in the short form (the acronym in fact, and without parentheses), also the first use of `\gls.` Also I wish this acronym was with the style that is defined by the command `\acronym`. Of course, the list of acronyms, next to each of them, it must appear to his description (in my example "Abcde Abcde Abcde"). You can do this? Is there anyone who can give me a hand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're asking quite a few things...

1. To always show the short form of acronyms, you have to use the command `\glsunsetall` after defining all of them with `\newacronym` commands.

   If you want this behavior only for a specific acronym you can put the optional argument `first=\glstext{<acronym>}` in `\newacronym` as in

   ```
   \newacronym[first=\glstext{AAA}]{AAA}{aaa}{Abcde Abcde Abcde}
   ```
2. To have the acronyms printed in the way you've described, you have to write the line

   ```
   \renewcommand*{\glstextformat}[1]{\textsf{\textsc{#1}}}
   ```

   Note that you can not use `\MakeLowercase` here, since the command refers to the acronym label. To achieve what you want, you have to write the second argument of `\newacronym` in lowercase, as in

   ```
   \newacronym{AAA}{aaa}{Abcde Abcde Abcde}
   ```
3. If you want the same font shapes in the List of Acronyms,  you have to write the line

   ```
   \renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textsf{\textsc{\mdseries #1}}}
   ```

Ultimately, the following MWE

```
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes}
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes}
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\acronimo}[1]{%
  \mbox{\sffamily\scshape\MakeLowercase{#1}}}

\renewcommand*{\glstextformat}[1]{\textsf{\textsc{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textsf{\textsc{\mdseries #1}}}

\makeglossaries
\newacronym{AAA}{aaa}{Abcde Abcde Abcde}
\glsunsetall

\begin{document}

\noindent First use: \gls{AAA}, and second use: \gls{AAA}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

gives the following output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @karlkoeller, it works as I wanted! To get the list of acronyms with the right font, however, we must also write the first argument of the command `\newacronym` in lowercase. Otherwise there would be only the first letter of the acronym in the list in lowercase. Thank you!

Comment: @Marco87 You're welcome. In regards of the list of acronyms, I can not confirm this.

Comment: In all probability depends on settings and personal definitions. Thank you so much again!