# Short form when acronym is first used in table

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I am referencing a table containing an acronym entry that has not been mentioned in the text before. I would like to print the acronym short form in the table (the acronym is used multiple times in the table) and print the long form when the acronym is used in the text for the first time. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside,fleqn]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel} % language listed last is default setting
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\usepackage{mhchem}

\usepackage[acronym,toc]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{LAr}{L\ce{Ar}}{Liquid Argon}

\begin{document}

some text ... \ref{SampleTable} ...

\begin{table}[!h] \centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|} \hline
& & \\ \hline \hline
\gls{LAr} & & \\ \hline
\gls{LAr} & & \\ \hline
& & \\ \hline
& & \\ \hline
& & \\ \hline
& & \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Sample Caption}
\label{SampleTable}
\end{table}

.... some text ... \gls{LAr}

\end{document}
```

Comment: With ```glossaries``` one can use ```\glsunsetall``` and ```\glsresetall``` like [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/170725/161492).

```\glsunsetall```
... table ...
```\glsresetall```
... text ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just use `\acrshort{}` or `\acs{}` (this requires the `shortcuts` options of the `glossaries` package) in the table and it will force use of the short form. Then the later `\gls{}` in the main text thinks it's the first use and chooses to display the long form on its own:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside,fleqn]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel} % language listed last is default setting
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\usepackage{mhchem}

\usepackage[acronym,toc,shortcuts]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{LAr}{L\ce{Ar}}{Liquid Argon}

\begin{document}

some text ... \ref{SampleTable} ...

\begin{table}[!h] \centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|} \hline
& & \\ \hline \hline
\acs{LAr} & & \\ \hline
\acrshort{LAr} & & \\ \hline
& & \\ \hline
& & \\ \hline
& & \\ \hline
& & \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Sample Caption}
\label{SampleTable}
\end{table}

.... some text ... \gls{LAr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried that, but I'm getting an error saying the \acs command is not known: ! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \acs
l.158 \acs
{LAr}

Comment: Sorry, you need to also add the `shortcuts` option when loading `glossaries`, my mistake. I updated the code above. :-)

Comment: Is there another command like \acs{} that can be used to print what is defined as plural of the acronym (instead of printing what is defined as firstplural)?

Comment: You mean like `\acsp{}`? You should take a look at the documentation; all of the commands (and their uses) are listed there.

Comment: Exactly. I'll go check it out.