# Use "ac" for showing the acronym but not the entire definition when called the first time

Tags: acronyms

Apologise for the bad title, I didn't succeed in summarizing what I mean.

I use the `acronym` package.

I set up a list of acronyms like

```
\begin{acronym}[AWGN]
 \acro{UK}{United Kingdom}
 \acro{USA}{United States of America}
\end{acronym}
```

that I recall using, for example:

```
\ac{UK}
```

When I use one particular acronym for the **first time**, it also shows its definition. For example, this text

```
London is the capital of \ac{UK}.
```

is shown as

> London is the capital of United Kingdom (UK).

But I only want

> London is the capital of UK.

How can I do that?

Comment: Think of using `\acs` instead.

Comment: Thank you!
So much effort for writing this thread and... It was only a matter of adding a "s"! :D
Thanks!

Comment: Could this be a duplicate? [Short form when acronym is first used in table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/228669/5764)

Comment: @Werner, now that I see that, yes it is. :\