# Problem with glossaries

Tags: glossaries

i'm having trouble with my glossaries library.

I declare the acronym DA as `\newacronym{DA}{DA}{Demandes d'Achats}` but when i write `émission des \gls{DA} et` it give me the following result in the glossary and in the text too. (I need a quick answer)

> Demandandes d'Achats (DA)

Comment: What are you expecting to see?  I imagine `\gls{DA}` gives the full name followed by the acronym on the first usage and just prints DA on future usages.  Perhaps you want [Glossaries Package: No long form the first time using an acronym](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/170725/106162)

Comment: alright but it is supoposed to print "Demandes d'Achat" and not "Deman**dan**des d'Achat"

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  please provide a small example that can be compiled, that shows the problem.  to help, we need something we can cut and paste to be able to experiment.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't noticed that!  Can you post an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/) which we can use to replicate this?  I.e. something compilable running from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`

Comment: Sorry i can't i have sensible information in it i can't spred thoses on the internet :/

Comment: Make a copy of your document and go through deleting everything but the minimum required to replicate this problem.  It should be possible to delete all such sensitive information and still replicate the problem.  If you can't do this then there's probably not much advice we can give.

Comment: I wonder whether it's a coincidence that the repeated letters form **and** as in Demand**and**es.

Comment: Well i have to go, i'll give it to them like that. I'll remain as a mistery. Thanks for trying to help at least :)

Comment: Less than half an hour is very rarely going to be enough time for somebody on this site to fix your problem.  Without a [Minimum Working Example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/) this becomes even harder.  If you are able to, please do come back and add an MWE to your question - even if you no longer have such an urgency/interest it might be of great value to others in the future.  If you do not want to post such an MWE please let us know so we can close the question.

Comment: Without a MWE this is just guesswork, but do you have a file with the extension `.glsdefs`? If you do, it's possible you might have had a typo that you fixed but the original misspelling is still in the `.glsdefs` file. In which case, delete the `.glsdefs` file and retry.

Answer (score 1):

Without an MWE it's hard to confirm, but I would suspect you have a typo somewhere.  I get the expected result:

```
\documentclass{article}

% Abbreviations
\usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist,toc]{glossaries}

\newacronym{DA}{DA}{Demandes d'Achats}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

% Use the acronyms
\'{e}mission des \gls{DA} et

\end{document}
```

Gives

> émission des Demandes d'Achats (DA) et